# Ubuntu 12.04 not displaying DVD drive

Tags: 12.04, dvd

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. After installing it and seeing that most of the stuff runs like I'm used to on Windows, but then there are some things that keep arising and I have to solve, so far this is the first I've needed help on:

I put a DVD-RW into my drive which is just a bunch of backed up files, the drive whirred away and eventually popped up Nautilus which displayed two folders with white icons 1's and 0's on them. I clicked on the file and found out they were not associated with any package, I also noted that there was no reference to DVD in the devices list.  Any idea on what is happening here?  Did I foget to install something?

Thanks for any help.

---

The last few lines read:

```
[  790.336832] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  800.760279] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[  889.816022] UDF-fs: Partition marked readonly; forcing readonly mount
[  889.847830] UDF-fs: INFO Mounting volume 'TJs_MiscStuff_1', timestamp 2006/10/10 11:53 (103c)
```

Comment: After you have inserted your DVD and the window appeared, open a terminal and type `dmesg`. If there is any problem reading the disc, you should see the error messages there.